# Saving data from a file into arrays

Tags: c, arrays, file, while-loop, save

I am trying to scan in this information:

```
00abcabc:abc123
01defdef:def456
02hijhij:hij789
```

into two arrays using this code:

```
FILE *dataLogin;

int i=0, numRecords;
char username[100][10], password[100][10];

dataLogin = fopen("login.dat", "r");

if (dataLogin == NULL){printf("Error");}

else {

    while (fscanf(dataLogin, "%s:%s\n", username[i], password[i])){i++;}

    fclose(dataLogin);

    numRecords = i;

    for(i = 0; i < numRecords; i++){printf("%s, %s\n", username[i], password[i]);}

    }

printf("complete");
```

The program compiles and runs but doesn't display anything. I believe I have isolated the fault to the while loop but I am stuck from there. Thanks!

Comment: Try checking the return from `fscanf`

Comment: @Dmitri How would one go about this?

Comment: Change your `while` condition to verify that it returns 2, eg. `(fscanf(...) == 2)` rather than just `(fscanf(...))`.  That'll only succeed if you read 2 strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
while (fscanf(dataLogin, "%[^:]:%s\n", username[i], password[i]) == 2){i++;}
```

scanf returns the number of field it red, so it will be 2 until the end of the file. And you also need to change the `"%s:%s\n"` to `"%[^:]:%s\n"`.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I ended up using the code from @fede1024.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you made the assumption that `fscanf` will return 0 on a failure. This appears to be incorrect, please check some documentation such as [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/). Search for the keyword `return` on the webpage.

It turns out you should run the loop while fscanf does not return `-1`. That should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with:

```
fscanf(dataLogin, "%s:%s\n", username[i], password[i])
```

%s:%s will not divide 00abcabc:abc123 in the two strings you want.
From the man pages of fscanf, for %s: "The input string stops at white space or at the maximum field width, whichever occurs first."
This means that the first %s will read the whole line: 00abcabc:abc123 and the second will read the second line etc. 
You need to find another way to divide each line in two strings.

edit: Leonardo's answer is indeed the reason your while loop doesn't terminate, but you will encounter this problem here even if you fix it

Answer (score 1):

//if it is fixed that the first part(A) in input file(A:B) is of length 8 and second part(B) is of length 7 then you can use the following changed code. Using feof() will also solve the problem of detecting end of file..

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *dataLogin;
  char ch;
  int i=0, numRecords;
  char username[100][10]={'\0'}, password[100][10]={'\0'};
  dataLogin = fopen("login.dat", "r");
  if (dataLogin == NULL){
    printf("Error");
  } else {
    while (!feof(dataLogin)){fscanf(dataLogin, "%8s:%7s", username[i], password[i]);i++; 
  }
  fclose(dataLogin);
  numRecords = i;
  for(i = 0; i < numRecords; i++){
    printf("%s, %s\n", username[i], password[i]);
  }
}

printf("complete");
}
```